# Invalid syntax in Python script of rnaQUAST

Tags: python-2.7

I have been trying to run a software, but since I am not an expert in python I do not know what this syntax error could be. I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "rnaQUAST.py", line 29, in <module>
  from metrics import TranscriptsMetrics
 File "/NFS/home/ffalcon/TOOLS/rnaQUAST1.4.0/metrics/TranscriptsMetrics.py", line 6, in <module>
  from general import UtilsCoverage
 File "/NFS/home/ffalcon/TOOLS/rnaQUAST1.4.0/general/UtilsCoverage.py", line 234
  covered_isoform_fraction_max = {id_isoform: isoforms_covered_fraction[id_isoform] for id_isoform in ids_isoforms_max}
                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: it's a dict comprehension. and it should work... What version of python is this running on?

Comment: I ran this on python 2.6 and the latest 2.7

Comment: that is valid: `print ({a : b for a,b in ((1,2),)})`. I don't see why the above shouldn't...

Comment: dict comprehension works on Python 2.7 upwards.  2.6 will fail for sure.  which version were you using when get above error?

Comment: Ok, so i added the line `print(sys.version)` to get the version that is interpreting. Turns out it first printed 2.7.9, but then printed 2.6, I checked what version was in /usr/bin/ and is 2.6.6, does this influence the way it loads other libraries? and is there a way to fix it without root access?

Answer (score 0):

`dict comprehension` works python2.7 upwards. Based on your comment, I believe that you got the error from python2.6 as below:
Python2.6

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mydict = {"a":1}
>>> mylist = ["a"]
>>> {x:mydict[x] for x in mylist}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    {x:mydict[x] for x in mylist}
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python2.7

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mydict ={"a":1}
>>> mylist=["a"]
>>> {x:mydict[x] for x in mylist}
{'a': 1}
```

Here's my solution:

```
>>> data = dict((x,mydict[x]) for x in mydict)
>>> data
{'a': 1}
```

Comment: I got the same error message using Python 2.7.12 and 2.7.9

Comment: have you used `sudo` to run your script or switched to other users to run it?

Comment: No, since I am running it on a cluster, I tried running it with the python version installed on it, and also locally installed Python to see if it fixed the problem